# How do I change the LSB of each pixel according to my message

Tags: java, arrays, steganography

I am trying to implement a simple encoding program where I can hide a message in the LSB of the pixels of an image. So far I've got the byte array from the message

```
    private static byte[] ConvertMessageToByte(String message,
        byte[] messageBytes) {
    // takes in the message and stores them into bytes
    // returns message byte array
    byte[] messageByteArray = message.getBytes();

    return messageByteArray;

}
```

I have also got the byte array for the corresponding image that i want to encode onto

```
    private static byte[] getPixelByteArray(BufferedImage bufferedImage) {

    WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage.getRaster();

    DataBufferByte buffer = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();

    return buffer.getData();

}
```

Till this point I don't quite understand my following steps after. Do I iterate through the image byte array and store each ARGB values in another byte array? Also how would I apply the message bit values to the pixels?

Answer (score 0):

```
private static byte[] ConvertMessageToByte(String message, byte[] messageBytes) {
    byte[] messageByteArray = message.getBytes();
    return messageByteArray;
}
```

Regarding this method: `convertMessageToBytes` is a better name as a lowercase first letter is more conventional as well as the fact that you are producing an array of multiple bytes and not just one. This method does not require the second `byte[]` parameter as it can be simplified to `return message.getBytes();` and produce the same effect. Furthermore, `String.getBytes()` is typically called in the parent function of this as it is not widely considered worthy of wrapping given that is one line. In conclusion: remove this method and use `byte[] ba = s.getBytes();` in your main code instead.

Personally, I process images as `3_BYTE_RGB` as that is how they are most commonly thought of and, indeed, represented on a physical monitor or printer and stored in the case of many image formats. HSL (LSB) is typically a user-end representation of colour. You should be thinking in RGB not HSL.

Instead of dealing with the image as a `byte[]`, use `int BufferedImage.getRGB(int x, int y)` as it's easier to do and easier to access.
The following function may be of use. I'll let you write the reverse.

```
private static int[] getColourAt(BufferedImage image, int x, int, y) {
  int rgb = image.getRGB(x, y);
  int r = rgb >> 16;
  int g = (rgb >> 8) % 256;
  int b = rgb % 256;
  return new int[] {r, g, b};
}
```

From there, you should loop through each pixel and adjust as you like.

Comment: Thanks Scruffy for clearing somethings up for me. I want to ask why have you used (rgb >> 8) % 256; for the green byte. Can you just clear that up for me?

Comment: For the green byte: we first take the whole 3-byte int and shift it right 8 places. The byte is in RGB format, so this removes the 8 bits of blue. `(rgb >> 8)` leaves us with 16 bits of (the sum of (the red byte * 256) and (the green byte * 1)). The final operation, taking the modulus of 256 removes anything greater than 1 byte and returns the last byte (the green byte). See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html for bit shifting and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html for modulus (int % int).

Comment: I have implemented the `getColourAt()` function but I cant seem to figure out how to change the LSB according to my message. I have a function called `getMessageBit()` which iterates through the message and singles out the bit values using a for loop `for(int i = 0; i < messageByte.length; i++)` and then use a variable called `int bit = (messageByte[i] >> j) &1`. I just cant seem to get my head around applying them values to the LSB values of my RGB array